# List of undertow error codes

Tags: jboss, wildfly, undertow

Is there a list error codes that undertow writes to the to the log file? I sometimes get errors with code UT005022 or with code UT005023 that look the same to me and sometimes different errors with the same error code:

```
2014-05-04 16:41:10,942 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-10) UT005022: Exception generating error page /error.xhtml: javax.servlet.ServletException: Cookie name "version" is a reserved token

2014-05-04 16:41:13,718 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-6) UT005023: Exception handling request to /error.xhtml: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Cookie name "version" is a reserved token

2014-05-04 08:16:22,861 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-9) UT005023: Exception handling request to /index.xhtml: javax.servlet.ServletException: viewId:/index.xhtml - Ansicht /index.xhtml konnte nicht wiederhergestellt werden.
```

Answer (score 1):

See `UndertowMessages.java` and `UndertowLogger.java` in the [source repository](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/). The id attribute of the `@Message` annotation corresponds to the UTxxxxxx prefix.